# Unable to register the default user model with django.contrib.admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to manage my `User` table with `django.contrib.admin`
But during I add the `User` table in admin, I had an issue that doesn't appear in admin site.

Here is my code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

assert admin.site.is_registered(User)  # Fails here
```

And when I added the other custom model, it works.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `admin.site.register(CustomUserAdmin, User)`?

Comment: There is many Admin class except `UserAdmin`, so I thought the decorator would be nice rather than `admin.site.register(CustomUserAdmin, User)`
And `admin.site.register()` doesn't work as well.

Comment: How about using `ModelAdmin` instead of `UserAdmin`? Isn't it work as well?

Comment: It wasn't a problem of `model.py`.
I should change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `auth.User` in `setting.py`
But still, thanks for helping me! @seuling

Comment: Oh then problem solved? Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify or implement the user model, you have to be aware of `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.
I changed `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `setting.py`, and it starts to work.

Thanks.